# What configurations to use in the current webpack for high performance in the frontend?

Tags: webpack

I am getting a notification in the compiler with webpack, regarding the size of files in production.

What kind of configurations do you use to have high performance in the frontend?
I read some articles on the web, but they are old versions and outdated, in the current version of the webpack what do you do?

**MY CONFIG:**

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [
    {
        mode: "production",
        entry: {
            indicators: path.resolve(__dirname, 'typescript', 'pages', 'Indicators.ts')
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].min.js',
            path:       path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'js'),
            publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src',  'js'),
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    extractComments: false,
                    warnings: false,
                    parse: {},
                    compress: {},
                    mangle: true,
                    output: null,
                    toplevel: false,
                    nameCache: null,
                    ie8: false,
                    keep_fnames: false,
                  },
            })]
        }
    }
];
```

**NOTE MESSAGE:**

```
$ webpack --watch --optimize-minimize

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: c53a46af60916f0d0f12
Version: webpack 4.29.6
Child
    Hash: c53a46af60916f0d0f12
    Time: 18457ms
    Built at: 2019-03-25 15:47:04
                Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    indicators.min.js  250 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  indicators
    Entrypoint indicators [big] = indicators.min.js
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [4] ./typescript/pages/Indicators.ts + 6 modules 146 KiB {0} [built]
        | ./typescript/pages/Indicators.ts 4.97 KiB [built]
        | ./typescript/controllers/BootstrapAccordion.ts 1.57 KiB [built]
        | ./typescript/controllers/HelpersMethods.ts 2.26 KiB [built]
        | ./typescript/controllers/WebStorage.ts 121 KiB [built]
        |     + 3 hidden modules
        + 3 hidden modules

    WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
    This can impact web performance.
    Assets: 
      indicators.min.js (250 KiB)

    WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
    Entrypoints:
      indicators (250 KiB)
          indicators.min.js


    WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
    You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement several strategies to better serve your bundle. Code splitting is a must and can be done in several ways:

1. Split vendor bundles.
2. Route-level code splitting.
3. Component-level code splitting.

**Vendor bundles**

To answer you question directly, here's the webpack config (part of it) that I found working nicely for vendor bundling:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ],
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom|react-redux|@material-ui)[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor'
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Of course you have to add/remove vendors depending on your app. You may also notice that we are using TerserPlugin for minification/uglyfication.

**Route-level code splitting**

Route-based code splitting with React is straightforward: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting. But you need to be careful not to overlap code in router-based bundles. Again, everything depends on your app structure.

**Component-level code splitting**

Webpack 4 supports component-based code splitting with dynamic imports out of the box: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports. Plus you gain amazing control over user experience if you integrate it with React Suspense and custom visual loaders.